# Finding all Logical Combinations of a Set

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, combinations, permutation

I am writing to ask if anyone knows how to go about this. I do not need the code, I would just like the logic behind doing this. So I have a set {A,B,C,D,E}. Now I want to find all combinations of and or OR operators amongst the values in the set.

Some examples below.

```
A and B and C and D and E 
A and B and C and D or E
A and B and C or D and E
```

From what I know there is 2^n-1 possibilities in the case above. So in the specific example above we would have 8 combinations.

In addition to the Above the values in the set can have two possibilities. For simplicities sake lets say A can be True or False. Likewise B,C,D and E. So what we would potentially have is something like the following :

```
A=True and B=True and C=True and D=True and E=True
A=True and B=True and C=True and D=True and E=False
A=True and B=True and C=True and D=True or E=True
```

and so on. So taking this into account we would have 2^(2 * n-1) combinations. So in our specific example above again we would have 16 combinations for a set of 4.

Is there an algorithm that already does this? If not would anyone have some logic to implement this in Java

Thanks,

Comment: You say there are `2^n-1` possibilities - that depends on your elements being in one particular order. So your `A,B,C,D,E` are more of a sequence than a set.

Comment: The number of possibilities with assignments doubles for each variable, so it is 2^(2*n-1), not 2*2^(n-1).

Comment: Do you want a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) ?

Comment: Another way to put what khelwood said: If you only consider the 2^(n-1) (not 2^n-1, BTW) combinations that can be formed by writing "AND" or "OR" between two variables, then you can't form any expression involving e.g. "A or C".  I doubt this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying you want to enumerate (perhaps print) all the distinct expressions of the forms you have described, for some set size `n`.  Since each one can be characterized by a set of flags (=True vs =False at positions 1 ... `n`, and And vs Or at positions 1 ... `n - 1`), you can represent each expression as an integer, with each flag corresponding to one (binary) bit.  If n has a value for which you could hope to explicitly enumerate all the possibilities, such an integer will be well within the range of a Java `long`.  For *comfortably* being able to enumerate all the possibilities, such an integer will be within the range of a Java `int`.

One way to proceed, therefore, would be to write a method to decode in-range integers into expressions according to their bit patterns.  You can then iterate over all the appropriate integers (i.e. `0` ... `(1 << (2 * n)) - 1`), and decode each one into the corresponding expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to get possible combination of five boolean values, you can do one thing -

1. Iterate a loop from zero to binary value "11111".
2. In each iteration you will get a unique combination of 0 and 1.
3. Convert 1 to true and 0 to false.

I hope below code will be helpful :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<boolean[]> result = new ArrayList<boolean[]>();
        int max_num = Integer.parseInt("11111", 2);
        for(int i=max_num; i>=0; i--)
        {
            String val = String.format("%5s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0');
            boolean[] arr = new boolean[5];
            char[] charArray = val.toCharArray();
            for(int j=0; j<charArray.length;j++)
            {
                if(charArray[j]=='1')
                {
                    arr[j]=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[j]=false;
                }
            }
            result.add(arr);
            arr=null;
            val=null;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        {
            for(boolean b: result.get(i))
            {
                System.out.print(b+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**To change the variable count :**

1. Replace same count of 1 with "11111". e.g. if variable count is 6, it should be "111111"
2. Change "%5s" accordingly. e.g. if variable count is 6, it should be "%6s".
3. Initialize array "arr" with same count.